# Why are carboard boxes hard to detect?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, data-science, object-detection

I'm trying to train a Neural Network how to detect cardboard boxes along with multiple classes of persons (people).

**Although it's easy to detect persons and correctly classifies them, it's incredibly hard to detect cardboard boxes.**

The boxes look like this:

[image: boxes with bounding boxes used to train neural network]

**My suspicion is that box is too simple of an object**, and the neural network has a hard time detecting it because there are too few features to extract from the object.

The division of the dataset looks like this:

```
personA: 1160
personB: 1651
personC: 2136
person: 1959
box: 2798
```

Persons are wearing different safety items, based on the items are classified, while detected as whole person, not just the item.

I tried to use following architectures:

```
ssd300_incetpionv2
ssd512_inceptionv2
faster_rcnn_inceptionv2
```

All of these are detecting and classifying persons much better than boxes. I cannot provide exact `mAP` (don't have it).

i used pertained CoCo model from tensorflow model zoo.

Any ideas why is so hard to detect boxes?

Thanks.

PS: I have asked this question on [data science stack exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/how-to-detect-cardboard-boxes-using-neural-network) but didn't got relevant answer.

Comment: This is a research question, not a programming one.

Comment: @window.document i believe that stackoverflow has bigger community than data science, cause even after bounty on that question i didn't got proper answer. the answer you mentioned is not answering my question at all

Comment: Also, your question is asking for ideas and not for help. Do include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) not just datasets and architecture names

Comment: Also please don't [cross post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: please understand this correctly: it's a nice and interesting question, but definitely not for SO. Comments above explain why. May be if you provide a [mcve] it becomes more suitable for SO, but only if there's a specific problem, not if a whole research is needed

Answer (score 1):

You are starting from a model pre-trained on COCO, which includes itself the "person" category, but not the "box" category so it sound normal to me that the box category is harder.
I don't think your hypothesis is correct since a CNN should be more than capable of extracting the right features for simple objects as well as complex ones.

Comment: do you have ideas how to improve the detections of those boxes? do i need much more data for boxes or train for longer period of time? Model has started to overfit pretty fast.

Comment: For sure adding instances of images with boxes will improve the result. Also try to look at detection outputs and see if you can spot some patterns in the way the network behave. You said you get overfitting so try to implement some measure against it (are you using augmentations?).

Comment: i am using random horizontal flip for all the objects, this function is included in tensorflow object detection api, i was not playing with default Dropout layers in mentioned architectures, if we are talking about number, how much more annotations do i need? at least as much as it is in pretrained models for other categories?

Comment: It's hard to answer you question since there aren't many theoretical foundations. You should experiment and find out yourself the right path to follow. Start by adding a few hundred images with boxes and see what happens. Play with the network architecture. The topic is too broad to answer precisely.